# If F is closed, int(F ∪ int(A)) = int(F ∪ A)?

Tags: general-topology

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$Let F be a closed subset of a topological space X, A be a subset of X.

> Proof: $\int(F\cup\int(A))=\int(F\cup A)$

As a beginner in point-set topology, proving that the sets on both sides of the equation include each other intuitively from left to right is obvious, but there are problems in the other direction.

To prove $\int(F\cup A)\subseteq\int(F\cup\int A)$, use a proof by contradiction:

Assume that there exists an $x\in\int(F\cup A)$ such that $x\notin\int(F\cup\int A)$.

Then $x\in X\setminus\int(F\cup\int A)$ and since $\int(F\cup\int A)$ is an open set, $X\setminus\int(F\cup\int A)$ is a closed set.

Here comes the problem: how to construct the contradiction?

I have tried to prove that $\forall x \in\int(F\cup A),x\in\int(F\cup\int A)$,but I don't know how to use the assumption that F is a closed set. So I have to resort to proof by contradiction, which allows me to use the properties of families of open sets in topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$My advice is that you try to use the definitions of $\int$ as the largest open set contained in another set, similarly to how it's very useful to use the definition of closure as: the smallest closed set containing another set. The proof by contradiction only works if you have a good notion beforehand of *why* (certain assumption) would be problematic, contradictory.

**HINT**:

The interior of a set is the largest open set contained in that set.

Notice that $F\cup\int A\subseteq F\cup A$, it is trivial that $\int(F\cup\int A)\subseteq\int(F\cup A)$, so you only need to show that $\int(F\cup A)\subseteq\int(F\cup\int A)$.

Since $\int(F\cup A)$ is the union of all open sets contained in $F\cup A$, to show that inequality we just need to show that if $U\subseteq F\cup A$ is open then $U\subseteq\int(F\cup\int A)$. Can you simplify that further, and then proceed?

Comment: Thanks for your hint.I finally realized why this problem has been troubling me for so long: I overlooked a simple fact that the complement of a closed set in an open set is still open. Once I realized this, it became clear that I could define an open set $U = ((U\setminus F )\cup (U\cap F))\subset F\cup A$ and the rest followed easily. Additionally, the idea of using proof by contradiction came from a similar problem, where the idea was to prove $x\in int(F∪A)\cap (X\setminus int(F∪intA))=\emptyset $ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: @YSouSerious Nice. That’s the idea: because $U\setminus F$ is open and contained in $A$, $U\setminus F\subseteq\mathrm{int}(A)$ and the rest follows as you say with $U=(U\setminus F)\cup(U\cap F)$.